# Custom node.tpl file not working in drupal 7 project

Tags: drupal-7

I've created a node file named node--product-display.tpl.php as suggested by theme developer module. But the changes I make to this file doesn't show up. I've also copied the node.tpl.php file in my templates directory. The changes in the latter one show up but that in the former one doesn't. Any suggestions? I'm a beginner in Drupal by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache. Go to "admin/config/development/performance" and click on "Clear cache" button.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.